# Audio player won't work with structure error when running callback

Tags: function, matlab, user-interface, structure

Ok, so I have looked at other problems concerning this error and none of them apply to mine.  I am trying to include a simple music player into my program in MATLAB, but every time I try to run it I get the error

```
Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

Error in Beam_Deflection_GUI_3_Music>Play_Music_Call (line 388)
n = get(S.listMusic,'Value');

Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

I am not sure why but here is my code:

```
MusicChoice = {'Message in A Bottle','Roxanne'};


S.Pa4 = uipanel('title','Music',...            
          'FontSize',12,...
          'BackgroundColor','white',...
          'Units','pixels',...
          'Position',[25 80 280 425],...
          'Parent',S.fh,...
          'fontweight','b',...
          'FontAngle','italic',...
          'visible','off');
S.listMusic = uicontrol('parent',S.Pa4,...
    'style','popupmenu',...
    'String',MusicChoice);


S.Play = uicontrol('parent',S.Pa4,...
    'style','push',...
    'string','Play',...
    'units','pix',...
    'pos',[100 100 20 20],...
    'callback',@Play_Music_Call);


 function [] = Play_Music_Call(varargin) 

     S = varargin{1};
     n = get(S.listMusic,'Value');
     MusicChoice = {'Message in A Bottle','Roxanne'};
     mChoice = MusicChoice(n,1);

     [y, Fs, nbits] = wavread(mChoice);
     S.player = audioplayer(y, Fs, nbits);
     play(S.player)

 end
```

Comment: This is line 388:                                                       n = get(S.listMusic,'Value');

Comment: Click just to the left of that line 388 to set a break point there, then re-run your code and it will pause immediately before that line. Then go to the command line and type `S` and hit enter and see what you get.

Comment: What does `whos S` give?

Comment: Name      Size             Bytes   Class     Attributes

    S        1x1                 8     double

Comment: can we move this to chat and Sorry that that came out funny the it was Name: S -- Size: 1x1 -- Bytes: 8 -- Class: Double -- Atributes: Blank

Comment: idk what you're trying to do here exactly based on only this code, but I can tell you that `S` is not what you think it is. Somewhere along the line you lost the struct and ended up with a double.

Comment: Well I am trying to create a popupmenu that has a list of songs. The user can choose a song and then hit the play button. the call back on the button takes the value gotten from the popupmeny and then uses it to find the string it is in the array *MusicChoice* it then inputs that string into the readwav func and then stores it and tries to play it

Comment: The first input to a callback is a handle pointing to the component for which the callback is triggered.

Comment: Ok so It set it to *Play_Music_Call(S)* but then I get the error to many input argument.

Comment: All right, I got the thing working.

Comment: @ponger3d I'm glad you got it working, for the sake of future users can you please write up what you did as an answer and then accept it?

Comment: Ok, So I found out that when I did *S = varargin{1}* I was saving the handle, which is a double and not a struct, to S. To work around this I had to nest the call back function in my larger Function which created the GUI , *Beam_Deflection_GUI_3*. I then got rid of the *S = varargin{1}* from the callback. It now works because it can access the S struck without having to re save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness so other people dont have to read all the comments first:

The asker posted this as a solution:

Ok, So I found out that when I did 
    `S = varargin{1}`

I was saving the handle, which is a double and not a struct, to `S`.

To work around this I had to nest the call back function in my larger Function which created the GUI , `Beam_Deflection_GUI_3`.

I then got rid of the 
`S = varargin{1}` 
from the callback.

It now works because it can access the `S` struct without having to re save it.